# Gnu radio C++ on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnuradio

I've read posts that Ubuntu 16.04 is not a good fit for newer gnuradio. Since I can't update Ubuntu so I had to install 3.7.9. It works fine except the C++ part. Because GRC won't generate C++ code (as far as I know, Python only), does someone have working C++ template/examples that would work? I followed the step-by-step tutorial but failed at the cmake/make stage. Something about the path isn't right but very limited information. So wonder if someone can help?

Comment: This is no signal processing question... Also seems like toy want features of a new version that nobody can port back to the old version. You're out of luck, unless you have the capacity to implement what you want yourself, you need to update your ancient system, use a modern system in a container or VM.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about signal processing. For questions about GNU Radio that aren't related to signal processing, please refer to the [official GNU Radio mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/) or to the [official GNU Radio chat channel](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/IRC).

Comment: also, what's said above is 100% right – if the GNU Radio project was able, within sensible efforts, to backport things to GNU Radio 3.7, they would. It's impossible, so to get new features, you need need new versions of GNU Radio. Also, Ubuntu 16.04 just left the regular support timeframe, and now there's no guarantee you'll even get security updates if you're not a paying customer of Canonical. So, really, "can't use modern Ubuntu": Tough luck, then you also can't use modern software :(

Comment: @MarcusMüller Maybe I was clear enough. I am not asking questions to use "new features". Just existing 3.7.9 versions like Gnuradio's official website lists. I've read your posts before about the difficulties to use 16.04 for newer version of gnuradio and I understand that. So my question is really much more basic than newer Ubuntu or new gnuradio. I was just asking a working C++ example/template in 16.04. I believe C++ should be working in 16,04 unless you say no.

Comment: you want c++ generation. That is a feature of GNU Radio 3.8.x, so yes you are asking to use features that are newer than the most modern version of GNU Radio that can be installed on Ubuntu 16.04! It won't work, full stop.

Comment: now I am confused: first of all, I don't need c++ generation. second is, my question is really is how to compile gnuradio c++ independently, without GRC and c++ generation. Are you saying c++ isn't working in 16.04 with this scale? Please confirm since it is contradict to what I understand.

Comment: ah! OK. so. Modern GRC (i.e., after 3.8.0.0) can generate C++ flow graphs. For that, it uses template files, and I thought you were asking for these. It seems that's not at all what you wanted! Then: the GNU Radio source tree at tag v3.7.9 contains quite a few C++-generated flow graphs. You should be able to find them by searching through all .cc files looking for `top_block`. (this all becomes a programming problem, not a signal processing problem, still.). I still, and strongly, recommend you solve whatever binds you to Ubuntu 16.04 instead.

Comment: ok, now you got my question fully :-). Yes, I have found those .cc files (and .h) files in the C++ API Reference manual. But I don't know how to compile them. Do you have some examples to compile/run them? Picking anyone of them to show the process is fine.